# Parsing out the right data with Nagios Graph

Tags: nagios

I am using check_iftraffic64.pl plugin to check the internet bandwidth being used on a fortigate unit.

This is the result I get:

> Average IN: 470.89Kbs (4.71%), Average OUT: 907.19Kbs (9.07%), Total
>   RX: 4175.91Gbits, Total TX: 4620.92Gbits|inUsage=4.71%;85;98
>   outUsage=9.07%;85;98 inBandwidth=470.89Kbs outBandwidth=907.19Kbs
>   inAbsolut=521988864000B outAbsolut=577614935040B

When I try to display it as a graph using Nagiosgraph I get this:

[image]

This obviously parses out Total RX and Total TX which is not what I want. I want the Average IN and Average OUT. I could use a regex after the result is returned to parse it out. But my question is, can it be done in a more elegant way that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about Nagiosgraph or Nagiosgrapher? They're 2 different add-ons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was right there in the Nagiosgraph to pick from. On the right Side there's this "+" button. I clicked it and it offered a variety of parses. Very handy!

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom regexps to the nagiosgraph map file, or replace their definitions that aren't suiting your needs.  (Mine is in /etc/nagiosgraph/map.)

There may be an easier or more elegant way to do it, but that's what I'd do.